# Determining the next observation with a 95% confidence.

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X$ follows a Poisson distribution with an unknown parameter $\mu$. The outcome of an experiment gave a value $X=625$. I want to determine, given this outcome, the interval in which the next outcome will fall with $95 \%$ probability.

I know how to estimate the $\mu$ parameter with $ 95 \%$ probability, but how do I estimate the actual value of $X$, not knowing $\mu$ in the first place?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this...none of which are exact. Are you looking for a Bayesian, Likelihood, or Classical approach?

Comment: The Poisson is here well approximated by the normal.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Classical, I think.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how are You able to tell?

Comment: Andre is using a common rule of thumb: with such a high count, $\mu$ is likely quite large, and hence the Poisson is well approximated by a normal. To convince yourself, plot the poisson distribution over the $\mu$ contained within the 95% CI. You'll see that the CDF of these distributions are close to that of a normal with the same mean and variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll offer two classical ways to predict a value:

1. Plug-in estimate: let $\hat \mu$ be your estimate of $\mu$ (e.g., the MLE), then model $X\sim Poi(\hat \mu)$. Use the upper and lower 2.5th percentiles of this estimated distribution as your predction interval. It won't be exact, but you should be reasonably close to 95% coverage.

   2. Percentile bounds with Bonferroni Correction: estimate the upper and lower 2.5th percentiles of the distribution as the upper and lower bounds of the 97.5% CI for these percentiles, respectively (this uses the Bonferonni correction for two simultaneous estimates). You can use Clopper Pearson or Wilson Score interval for each of these percentiles. This will give you a conservative bound on the 95% prediction interval.